# how to append multiple columns of data to tab delimited file efficiently in one-pass

Tags: unix, sed

So far I have figured how to add just one column .I have two more columns.
I have simplified my code here but actually I source the columns as variables from another file and I have 100 such files each 50 MB that I should add these columns.

This is input file

```
1|True
2|Fals
```

I want the output to be

```
1|True|2018-05-10|2018-05-11|2018-05-12
2|Fals|2018-05-10|2018-05-11|2018-05-12
```

I have written this

```
sed -i "s/.$/|2018-05-10/" $file
```

Comment: Can you describe the structure of your file in a bit more detail. Depending on that `paste` or `awk` might work well.

Comment: Remove `.` from your `sed` command.

Comment: @andrew.punnett -Not sure I got your question..I have over 100 files sitting in a unix directory and all I have to do it source 3 dates as variables from one file and use those dates as my data to append to rest of all the files

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** As per OP dates are not system dates they are variables then adding following.

```
awk -v var_1=$(var1) -v var_2=$(var2) -v var_3=$(var3) '{print $0 OFS var_1 OFS var_2 OFS var_3}' OFS="|"   Input_file
```

Where `var_1`, `var_2` and `var_3` are `awk` variables and `var1`, `var2` and `var3` are bash variables.

---

With GNU `date` following may help you on same.

```
awk -v today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d) -v tomorrow=$(date +%Y-%m-%d --date="+ 1 day") -v day_after=$(date +%Y-%m-%d --date="+ 2 day") '{print $0 OFS today OFS tomorrow OFS day_after}' OFS="|"   Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -v today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d) -v tomorrow=$(date +%Y-%m-%d --date="+ 1 day") -v day_after=$(date +%Y-%m-%d --date="+ 2 day") '
{
  print $0 OFS today OFS tomorrow OFS day_after
}
' OFS="|"   Input_file
```

In case of saving changes into Input_file itself append `> temp_file && mv temp_file  Input_file` to above code too.

Comment: My dates are not consecutive like today,tommorrow..I just made them up for this example.I have to source those dates from another file as varaiables

Comment: @cheapcoder, please try my EDIT code and let me know if this is what helps you?

Comment: It did not work.I am trying to execute it via bash script..Do you think any changes are needed to your edited code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following input file:

```
$ more file
1|True
2|Fals
```

Then you can use the following `sed` command to process it in one pass:

```
DATE1=2018-05-10; DATE2=2018-05-11; DATE3=2018-05-12; sed -i "s/$/|$DATE1|$DATE2|$DATE3/" file
```

output:

```
$ more file
1|True|2018-05-10|2018-05-11|2018-05-12
2|Fals|2018-05-10|2018-05-11|2018-05-12
```

You can assign any value to your three dates by using `date +%Y-%m-%d --date="SPECIFIC DAY"` or any other values

Comment: I tried this earlier..It did not work with multiple columns and it overwrites last changes